# como puedo recorrer el siguiente json

Tags: javascript, json

tengo este json y quiero mostrar el valor de sus claves ya se por consola o por una ventana.

```
{ 
    "commerce_brand":"MASTERCARD",
    "commerce_brand":"visa",
    "commerce_brand":"otros"
}
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: y con que lenguaje vas a leer esa data?

Comment: con javascript  ..

Comment: Si es javascript tal y como indicas en los tags, utiliza [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries) para recorrer las claves y valores.

Comment: El json es invalido puesto que las claves no se pueden repetir. Deberia ser { "commerce_brand": [ "MASTERCARD", "visa", "otros" ] }

Comment: tambien te funciona el [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys)

Comment: @osiris85 al inicio el OP no indicaba en sus eqtiquetas el uso de JS por eso se le preguntó

Comment: @shadow perdona, cuando lo vi desde la sección de preguntas me aparecía directamente con javascript, no era por contradecir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El json como lo presentas simpre te arrojará como resultado **"commerce_brand":"otros"** ya que estas utilizando el mismo indice o key con diferentes valores, por lo que siempre estas sobreescribiendo y el resultado sera siempre el último:

```js
let json = { 
  "commerce_brand":"MASTERCARD",
  "commerce_brand":"visa",
  "commerce_brand":"otros"
}

console.log(json);
```

Me imagino que quieres quieres obterne varios valores dentro de **commerce_brand**, para ello **commerce_brand** debe ser un array así:

```js
let json = { 
  "commerce_brand":["MASTERCARD",
                "visa",
                "otros"]
}

console.log(json);
```

y lo puedes recorrer así:

```js
let json = { 
  "commerce_brand":["MASTERCARD",
                    "visa",
                    "otros"]
}

json["commerce_brand"].forEach((elemento, indice) => {
  console.log(elemento);
});
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 4):

La especificación [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4) referente a JSON dice que los nombres de objeto deberían ser únicos. Aunque esto es sólo una recomendación es mucho mas práctico si tienes que convertirlo a objetos en javascript. Tu estructura podrías convertirla para manipularla facilmente de esta forma:

```
 { "commerce_brand": [ "MASTERCARD", "visa", "otros" ] }
```

Comment: Eso que dices es cierto pero no responde a la pregunta de cómo recorrer y mostrar un json

Comment: La pregunta dice "El siguiente json", lo de recorrer un JSON ya tiene miles de respuestas en SO o Internet. Saludos